# Seagate Barracuda 1.5Tb HDD 7200.11 Unresponsive

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate Barracuda 1.5Tb HDD 7200.11 that i put in an external case. I was using it on an XP desktop, ubuntu laptop and windows 7 laptop. One day my computers stopped recognizing it. ubuntu would show the drive for a few minutes, but when attempting to access the drive it would say the dbus was busy, then the drive would vanish after a set amount of time. the drive would still be powered and running from what i could hear (but the sounds could be from the case fan). Ubuntu would show the HDD root as empty. windows 7 would say the drive was not formatted and ask to format. I have attempted to connect the drive to another sata to usb tool and its doing the same thing. so its not a hard drive case problem.

I followed some steps in upgrading the firmware from seagates website and now the HDD root directory shows the folders but the drive is still unresponsive and after the set amount of time will vanish. so the drive shows that its half full and i can see the directories on the HDD root. but if i click on anything in the HDD root, ubuntu gets the dbus is busy and windows 7 gives me an hour glass. seagate has told me my drive is not one of the defective ones and that they have never seen a problem like mine. Can anyone help me?

If i can get the drive to be responsive and stay connected long enough, then maybe i can pull the files off of the drive and decommission the drive. My objective is get all the files off the drive and never use the drive after getting all my files. I already have a new 2Tb drive to copy the files onto. I just need to clone the defective 1.5tb over to the 2tb drive.

I was able to rule out my hard drive case by connecting the hard drive to this [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-eSATA-Drive-Docking-Station/dp/B001IOPIRM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001IOPIRM)
and the drive was doing the same thing. as of right now i have only tested the drive using external to usb solutions. My next test is putting in a computer to see if sata can see it.

also is this unmounting a common thing with segate barracuda 7200.11 models? I can't be the only one getting this. I have never had a drive do this. I have had drives get bad sector errors then die in the past, but this unmounting is new to me.

also when i first got the drive i knew i was going to use it for windows and linux systems so i set it up with NTFS. So the solutions may need to know that the format of the drive is NTFS.

My first mistake was not making a backup. Some one had told me years ago drives only get worn out if used all the time. Being that this was a drive I would turn on every so often to put files onto it. I expected it to have a long life due to not putting a lot of use on it. I have learned my lesson and once I get this solved ill be setting up a real backup strategy along with also using a RAID.

Comment: Sounds like the drive is dead...

Comment: for the short time after i turn it on i can see the files in the root drive. the data is still there. I just need to keep it on long enough to get the files off. after the drive vanishes all i have to do is turn the drive case off and back on and its back for the same amount of time.

Comment: The fact that it 'works' for a short time doesn't mean time is a factor.  More likely it dies when it tries to read from a specific location or when a write happens.  The most effective way to recover from a dying drive like this is to replace the faulty drive and restore from backup.  If you don't have a backup, then your time would be better spent implementing a backup strategy IMO.  Filenames aren't stored at the same location the actual files are, you probably don't have the data you think you do..  Read up on [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) to understand that better.

Comment: You are going to have to accept that its very likely your HDD is not going to stay mounted long enough to do any sort of data transfers.  I assume you have tried without the USB external case right?  This means using a SATA cable itself instead of USB.

Comment: I will put the drive into a desktop and see if i can get to the files. so far i have only attempted using sata to usb external solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Get a disk which is at least as big as the current disk, and a Linux rescue disk - for example http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/

Use "ddrescue" to do a bit copy of the drive to the new drive.   If it dies part way through the process, restart the process and ddrescue will continue where it left off.  I guess if it dies part way you can work on the assumption its a hardware failure.  [ DDRescue's sole purpose is to try and copy as much data off a dying disk as it can ]

If DDRescue mirrors the drive you will have a bit copy of the drive.  If its readable, great.  If not, you can probably assume there are errors with the file system which you may need to remedy.  If you can't remedy them, depending on your luck and the content, you might be able to get some of it off using photorec.

Good luck !

Comment: Could you elaborate more with instructions this looks to be a good solution. I'm new to ddrescue.

Comment: I have a 2tb drive that i have not formatted yet, that i plan to use to clone the defective 1.5tb drive. Should i format it prior to ddrescue and if so should it match the NTFS format the defective drive has?

Comment: Unfortunately it will require a bit of "googling arround", particularly if you are not familiar with Linux.  GNU DD Rescue is a command line program which takes 3 parameters - the (dying) source disk, the target to pull the data to and a log/tracking file.   Provided you have some space for the tracking file - this can be a USB key if necessary - the easiest way is to use the raw drive, in which case no point in formatting it.   Look at http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue.

Comment: If the data is very important to you and you are new to Linux, you may want to find and pay someone from your local LUG to help you, as you need to identify the devices correctly.

Comment: I'm not new to linux, but i'm new to DDRescue. I have been working on ubuntu for years. I would have trouble with advanced driver configurations but to use ubuntu and setting up ubuntu servers i have done multiple times in the past. I'm more into the server side of ubuntu then the drivers and kernel configurations. I would need help if it requires knowledge of drivers and advanced kernel configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Put the drive directly in the computer, and not connected via external enclosure. That might get rid of the problems (and it might also be the case that a enclosure is problematic, not the drive itself).

Comment: I had connected the drive to another external enclosure to rule out the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very optimistic answer, but having a drive randomly vanish and reappear in a file manager is usually a sign that the drive is, in short, dead.

I would definitely try hooking the drive up to internal power and SATA connectors just to rule out any possible power or compatibility issues caused by external enclosures.

I also agree that it's possible the drive has already lost files and is having issues because it can't find them or even orient itself to read from the disk.

Comment: Its possible there may be some data corruption but i feel like it must not be much if the root folder still looks normal. but i could be wrong.

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon Its very likely there isn't ANY data corruption.  What you describe would indicate a mechanical problem

Comment: i hope your right Ramhound